# ALTER TABLE ADD AFTER works in SQL query but not in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, alter

When I run SQL query in phpMyAdmin directly it works; however, running the same query from PHP file does not affect the database table and no errors are thrown also.

```
ALTER TABLE tender_230115 ADD avt DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL AFTER vpm
```

PHP Version 5.3.28. Database connection is indeed established. When I run:

```
$test_query = "ALTER TABLE tender_230115 ADD avt DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL AFTER vpm";
$upload_test = $conn->query($test_query);
```

Nothing is affected in the database table, while var_dump($upload_test) = bool(false).

Quotes and backticks do not help also. Using the **mysqli** driver.

Comment: In php code, the last line has to be first and quotes are missing.

Comment: You use backticks for table and column names not qutoes

Comment: @Mihai Backticks also not working. They are reversed, and they were text when I was wrinting this questions. Don't know why it looks like a part of code now.

Comment: @Mihai do you mean F5? I'm doing it kind of constantly.

Comment: Show how you connect to the db

Comment: @Mihai done in problem description.

Comment: When you use directly the names in php does it work?

Comment: Better yet, don't quote the column or table names at all.

Comment: Nope, also no changes. Thought I cannot leave php variables in SQL requests without singnle quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piggy backing off of what @Keo and @Mihai said above, your code needs to be:

```
$existing_tender = "tender_230115"; 
$existing_user = "avt"; 
$penultimate_name = "vpm";
$insert_column = "ALTER TABLE `$existing_tender` ADD `$existing_user` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL AFTER `$penultimate_name`";
$upload = $conn->query($insert_column);
```

To see more information on an error that happened, you can add the following code below the code above:

```
var_dump($conn->error);
```

**Edit** with what the author specified his issue was. This was pulled from the comments below on this answer. Placing it here so that it's more clear what the actual issue was:

> Ok, so something else to look into is permissions. Is the mysql user
>   in PhpMyAdmin the same as the user you are using in PHP? For example,
>   you might login to PhpMyAdmin with your personal account, however you
>   might have a different project account that you are using for your
>   mysqli connection. If this is the case, ensure that your project mysql
>   account has permissions to ALTER tables.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple. By saying $existing_tender = "tender_230115" I just ment its value. Surely, I declared variables before SQL statement. Sorry if I confused you a bit.

Comment: Ah ok sorry it was not clear that the variables were declared before. Do you have any errors appearing in your error log? @Snowman

Comment: Nope, it runs without throwing errors, but table in phpMyAdmin has no changes.

Comment: Some other things to look at:
1) Are you connecting to the same database? You might check your connection settings
2) var_dump the contents of $upload and see what is being returned
3) Log into the database via the terminal and see if the changes are made there but possibly not in PhpMyAdmin? (Not sure why this would be but worth a check)
@Snowman

Comment: Well, it just returns FALSE. DB is the same.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO? Both return false upon failure in PHP. You can get more information on the error happening, though, with certain methods. For PDO, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php @Snowman

Comment: For mysqli (I see your updated description above), you can look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to find error details. I updated my answer to reflect. @Snowman

Comment: Oh, it says  Trying to get property of non-object. That was $upload->error;

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `$upload->error`, you should be doing `$conn->error` according to the [PHP mysqli error page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). @Snowman

Comment: Ok, so something else to look into is permissions. Is the mysql user in PhpMyAdmin the same as the user you are using in PHP? For example, you might login to PhpMyAdmin with your personal account, however you might have a different project account that you are using for your mysqli connection. If this is the case, ensure that your project mysql account has permissions to ALTER tables. @Snowman

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Lea Crawford was definitely right pointing at **user permissions**. Cpanel provides you with MySQL Databases menu where user can pick his username and change permissions to be able to use ALTER TABLE SQL request from PHP file. The same is relevant to UPDATE, CREATE and other SQL commands.

Comment: Awesome! Glad the issue was found. I updated my answer above to reflect so that it's more clear what the solution was.